# How to handle NullPointerException in a custom way

Tags: java, oracle

I am using a oracle connection to process some file.Here i have  an xml file  that supply some condition that  be either true or false.Upon which the oracle connection will be loaded or not.So that much i am able to handle,but the problem is that when the condition is false the  the connection is closed but the class which is calling the connection is getting an NULLPointerException.I have to handle the Nullpointer with a proper message ...i am posting the code....

Supplying the connection...

```
   try {
        String s;
        if ("DB2".equalsIgnoreCase(db)) {
            s = "jdbc:db2://" + host + ':' + port + '/' + sid;
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(s, user, pwd);
        } else if ("ORACLE".equalsIgnoreCase(db)) {
            if(isProcessed.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            s = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + host + ':' + port + '/' + sid;
            //s = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + ":" + port + ":" + sid;
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(s,user,pwd);
            }else{
                try{

                    conn.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Aborted by user");
                }

            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error : Unsupported DataBase : " + db);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to load Driver class ", e);
    }
    return conn;
}
```

the class which is calling the connection ...

```
public class HuaGPRSFileExecutor extends FileExecutor {

protected void processFile(PathHandler output, FileStatus fileStatus) throws Exception {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> record = HuawieGPRSParser.persefile(fileStatus);
    for (String eventName : record.keySet()) {
        if (eventName == null || "null".equals(eventName)) continue;
        ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> events = (ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>) record.get(eventName);
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            new HuawieGPRSCDRHandler().populateDB(eventName, events, fileStatus, conn);
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            new HuawieGPRSCDRHandler().generateFile(output, events, fileStatus);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Connection conn = getConnection();`
is this the line getting null pointer exception?

Comment: can i print a proper message instead of this stacktrace

Comment: `Connection conn = getConnection();  if (conn == null) {//dosomething}`

Comment: if(conn != null){
                 Connection conn = getConnection(); 
                 
                }else{
                 System.out.println("handled ");
                } did that still getting the stacktrace

Comment: You should `.close()` your connection in a `finally` block -- and create it before `try`.

Comment: @fge it is created before try

Comment: So what is the issue with current implementation.Create custom exception class and handle it

Comment: This is not what I see in the current code extract...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            if(conn== null)
              {

      //You can either print the message saying
```

//connection is null or fire a custom
//exception in case you need handle it via exception

```
               }
            else{

            new HuawieGPRSCDRHandler().populateDB(eventName, events, fileStatus, conn);

                }
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```